# Move to Destination Controller if data is validated

Tags: ios, storyboard

Sorry if this question is asked before . I want my loginSegue (push) to open destination controller if login credentials are valid.

My First Controller and next controller are connected by push segue (login segue)

First Controller has login button and on its press event i am calling performSegueWithIdentifier

I have done this so for

```
- (IBAction)loginMe:(id)sender { 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"])
    {
        if ([[nameTextField text] isEqualToString: @"admin"] && [[passwdTextField text] isEqualToString:@"1234"]) {

           // destinationVC *vc= [[destinationVC alloc] init];
          // [segue destinationViewController] =vc;
           // destinationVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

         // how i set destinationVC as my destination controller ?

            NSLog(@"Credentials Match");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Credentials dont Match");
        }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not about technicality, it's about Logic.

"prepareForSegue" will be called as soon as you call "performSegueWithIdentifier". So, you had to check your validation before calling "performSegueWithIdentifier"

```
- (IBAction)loginMe:(id)sender { 
if([txtEmailField.text isEqualToString: @"username@domainname.com"] && [txtPassword.text isEqualToString: @"password"])
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
}
else
{
   [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please enter valid e-mail address and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

Comment: either credentials validate or not it moves to destination controller. i was thinking that there will be a way to handle it programmatically. I am learning  IOS sorry if i am asking very basic question

Comment: You must be calling a webservice for Logging in the user. Am I right ?

Comment: no i am comparing textField's text with static string values

Comment: Thanks its working. I forgot commenting    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self]; outside if-else statement

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your storyboard segue from **Push Segue to a Custom segue**.

To do it you will need to delete your exist push segue and create a new one, **dragging from one viewController to another** (you dont need to drag from the button), after that you will need to manually call the segue with performSegueWithIdentifier, inside the loginMe function.

I hope it helps.